# How to setup VPN with Pre-Shared-Key

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I've basically searched around for this problem but there seem not to be a straight answer.
I have an ubuntu server running on Vultr and would like to setup a VPN.

The VPN should be able to connect to two clients using two different pre-shared-keys.
How can i setup this VPN to use and connect to the clients using the PSKs?

I have tried to use [this guide](https://sysadmins.co.za/setup-a-site-to-site-ipsec-vpn-with-strongswan-on-ubuntu/) but can't seem to figure out why i need to generate a new PSK since i already have two sent from the clients

I heard openVPN is good. Does it support PSKs?

Comment: Check out PiVPN.  It lets you create accounts for each client and generates .ovpn files (It's OpenVPN) that you can use to configure the client software.

Comment: I have just two details for use in connecting to the other servers. I don't have access to them.

Answer (score 1):

I invested days into trying many ( vpn server + client ) and this is by far the easiest to install and use ... on your remote ubuntu server issue following to install vpn server

```
wget https://git.io/vpnsetup -O vpnsetup.sh && sudo sh vpnsetup.sh
```

at bottom of output from above it will show something similar to

```
Server IP: 111.222.333.444
IPsec PSK: foobar
Username: vpnuser
Password: yoyoyo

Write these down. You'll need them to connect!

Important notes:   https://git.io/vpnnotes
Setup VPN clients: https://git.io/vpnclients
```

then simply read client setup using above link ...  its free and open source

client works on linux / android / osx / iOS / Window$

> PSK stands for Pre-Shared-Key

see details at https://github.com/hwdsl2/setup-ipsec-vpn

Comment: thank you for the input. however, i am to connect to the other servers with a PSK provided by the administrator of those servers. I can set up the VPN alright, but how do i connect using the PSK sent to me?